# Incomplete migration wordpress

Tags: wordpress, web

I have a website, and I had a problem with the server, I needed to migrate it, but my partner copied all the files from the FTP in a folder without doing a backup from the db, and the site I was working on is not even coded, is based on plugins, (I don't even know how it works, it is a theme and some plugins editing it).

Now the page only shows the basic theme without any of the information it has.

Is there any way to restore the site?

Comment: Are you saying that the old site was using WordPress, and that you want to migrate the site to new hosting, without changing the theme or plugins? You'll need the DB.

Comment: but I dont have the exported db, where can I find it in the files?

Comment: If you had a backup plugin installed there's a chance you might find it amongst the wp-content folder. If you didn't have a back plugin installed you'd need to either log in to the old site and export the content using WP's export options, or use PHPMyAdmin to export the database.